# Javascript garbage collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, garbage-collection

I have base class which extends Backbone.View class.
I pass a Jquery DOM element through the constructor, is this object a candidate for garbage collection?

```
var MainView = BaseView.extend({
  initialize: function(o) {    
    this.container = o.myJqueryDomElement;
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.container.append(this.$el);
  },
  dispose: function() {
    this.remove();
  }
});
```

in some point in my code I do this:

```
var mainView = new MainView({
  myJqueryDomElement = $('#content')               
});
```

Comment: And... what is your question?

Comment: Yeah, and I also have...

Comment: And? What is the problem or what is not working? A little more effort to show what your problem is would be much appreciated!

Comment: @user1998458: Is garbage collection part of the ECMA standard at all?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake, I was editing and saved without wanting to post!

Comment: Can someone vote to re-open?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should pass the jQuery element in as `el`, so

```
var MainView = BaseView.extend({
    initialize: function(o) {    
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.html(someTemplate)
    },
    dispose: function() {
       this.remove();
    }
});

var mainView = new MainView({
  el: $('#content')               
});
```

Then this will be available throughout the object as a jQuery object via `this.$el` and the view shouldn't know about its container just the element it lives in. So if you want this to be the main view change your selector to be `$('#content .main')` or just `$('#main')`

Comment: I understand your point about container, but my question is about garbage collection. Instead of the jQuery element, I would pass an object.